# Trying to make a dynamic dialog bash menu (form, input, info, fselect)

Tags: bash, user-interface, dialog, calibre

I want to make a script to add some books or folder to calibredb, i want to use bash gui with dialog.
I'm pretty new and learning by myself so the code can be weird..

My main_menu look like this :

```
function main_menu(){

    MENU=$(dialog --clear --title "Calibre" \
        --backtitle "Add Books" \
        --menu "What to do ?" \
        0 0 0 "C" "Choose a book or a folder" "M" "Enter metadata infos" "L" "Add selected Book(s)" "D" "Change default Directory for books" "E" "Exit" \
        2>&1 >/dev/tty)
        
    if [ $MENU = "C" ];then
        select=$(file_selector $mnt)
    elif [ $MENU = "M" ];then
        form_data
    elif [ $MENU = "L" ];then
        if [ -d $select ];then
            add_folder $select
        elif [ -f $select ];then
            if [[ $file == *.cbz || $file == *.pdf ]]; then
                add_book $select
            else
                error "Books should has extension .cbz .pdf"
            fi
        else
            error "No file or folder selected"
        fi
    elif [ $MENU = "D" ];then
        NEWDIR=$(file_selector $mnt)
    
    elif [ $MENU = "E" ];then
        exit
    fi
    
}
```

When I type M to go to function submenu form_data it works at launch, but not if i go in others submenus first. Also i used if statement and not case because i can't get it, always errors at launch.
My form_data function is :

```
function form_data() { 
    auth=""
    serie=""
    tag=""
    ind="1"

    echo "form data" 
    exec 3>&1
    IFS=$'\n'
    VALUES=($(dialog --clear --ok-label "Submit" \
          --backtitle "Calibre" \
          --title "Manager" \
          --form "Add a book" \
        15 50 0 \
        "Author's name:" 1 1    "$auth"     1 20 30 0 \
        "Serie's name:"    2 1  "$serie"    2 20 30 0 \
        "Tag:"    3 1   "$tag"      3 20 30 0 \
        "Serie's index (int):"     4 1  "$ind"  4 20 30 0 \
        2>&1 1>&3))
    
    exec 3>&-
    main_menu
}
```

As you can see i call the main_menu at the end cause i want to back to it when i Submit the form. Pretty not sure that's the way to do this.

Also a lot of info dialog box doesn't work properly.

```
function error() {
    dialog --clear --title "Error : " --msgbox $1 10 50
    sleep 1
    main_menu
}
```

And finally the goal is to call the add_book or add_folder function to put in calibre, i didn't try but i expect to show a progress bar in dialog but i don't if the calibredb can return it's progress  :

```
function add_folder() { 
    echo "add folder "
    echo $1
    echo ${VALUES[@]}
    nbBooks=$(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l);
    listBooks=($(find $1 -maxdepth 1 -type f))
    for (( i; i<=$nbBooks; i++ )); do
            calibredb add -a "${VALUES[0]}" -s "${VALUES[1]}" -T "${VALUES[2]}" -S "$i" "${listBooks[$i]}" --with-library /home/gregory/books

    done
    main_menu
}
```

After a lot of headache, reading documentation, you are all my last hope to understand the way to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use a variable `$file` that you never assign. Is that supposed to be `$select`?

Comment: Remember to quote your variables. Paste your code into shellcheck.net to find all your simple problems.

Comment: Use a loop to repeat the main menu, not recursion.

Comment: I tried with a loop for the main menu but I can't go in any submenu..

Comment: Thanks for the advices, the variable file not supposed to exist, it's select variable I didn't saw that mistake!

Comment: the problem with a while loop on my main menu, it doesn't store my variable like folder, or the form..

Comment: I don't see why that would make a difference. Assigning a variable is the same whether you recurse or iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use recursion to repeat the main menu, use a top-level loop.

```
function main_menu(){
    while :; do
        MENU=$(dialog --clear --title "Calibre" \
            --backtitle "Add Books" \
            --menu "What to do ?" \
            0 0 0 "C" "Choose a book or a folder" "M" "Enter metadata infos" "L" "Add selected Book(s)" "D" "Change default Directory for books" "E" "Exit" \
            2>&1 >/dev/tty)
        case "$MENU" in
        C)
            select=$(file_selector $mnt) ;;
        M)
            form_data ;;
        L)
            if [ -d "$select" ];then
                add_folder "$select"
            elif [ -f "$select" ];then
                if [[ "$select" == *.cbz || "$select" == *.pdf ]]; then
                    add_book "$select"
                else
                    error "Books should have extension .cbz or .pdf"
                fi
            else
                error "No file or folder selected"
            fi ;;
        D)
            NEWDIR=$(file_selector $mnt) ;;
        E) 
            exit ;;
        esac
    done    
}
```

Then your other functions should simply return rather than calling `main_menu`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that works with case, i don't know what i forgot !
So i came back to my first problem : when i fill the form or select a folder my variables are not stored or modified ..

Comment: I can't think of any reason why they wouldn't be stored. Which variables aren't working?

Comment: I always go else for L case, No file or folder selected. So I can't get the $select value

Comment: You can't use `L` until after you choose a folder with `C`.

Comment: Are you sure `file_selector` works properly? When you're debugging a script, put `set -x` at the beginning so you see a transcript of all the statements. Then you'll see what gets assigned to `$select`.

Comment: Thanks very much, maybe because of redirections issues i couln't get any variables. Now it works I'll read more about redirections ! Thanks again !

Comment: Maybe the way you were doing redirections ran some functions in a subshell. Its variable assignments won't be visible in the main script.